# Excel Macro, vlookup function works slow, ways to speed up macro

Tags: performance, excel, vba

Hello stackexchange community.

I've built a simple tables converter, the main function of which is to convert the table from

```
1a Value
1b Value
1c Value
1d Value
```

to

```
    a     b     c     d
1 Value Value Value Value
```

Unfortunately, the macro runs pretty slow (~ 3 lines per second for one column).

I'd really appreciate if someone could take a look at my piece of code and suggest the way to speed it up.

Here's the piece of code:

```
Dim LastFinalList As Integer: LastFinalList = Sheet1.Range("O1000").End(xlUp).Row

For Col = 16 To 19

For c = 2 To LastFinalList

searchrange = Sheet1.Range("J:L")

lookfor = Sheet1.Cells(c, 15) & Sheet1.Cells(1, Col)
CountFor = Application.VLookup(lookfor, searchrange, 3, False)

If IsError(CountFor) Then
Sheet1.Cells(c, Col).Value = "0"
Else
Sheet1.Cells(c, Col).Value = CountFor

End If

Next c

Next Col
```

Thanks in advance and best regards!

UPD:

The Data in unconverted table looks like this (e.g):

```
                      Updated by Macro  
Value Number Type    Key  Count Average Value
  10    1     a      1a     2       20
  30    1     a      1a     2       20
  40    1     b      1b     1       40
  50    1     c      1c     1       50
```

So it is also required to calculate averages of repeating types, create a unique list of Numbers (which is LastFinalList in my case) and finally convert it to this:

```
Number  a    b    c
   1    20   40   50
```

`application.vlookup`seraches by Number&Type Key, which is also assigned in the unconverted table by macro. The same time those Keys are counted, in order to calculate average for the repeating ones.

Everything works in a blink of an eye till it comes to `'to update final table` part.

Full Code:

```
    Sub ConvertToTable()

Dim LastMeter As Integer: LastMeter = Sheet1.Range("I1000").End(xlUp).Row

Sheet1.Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(LastMeter, 9)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheet1.Range("O2"), Unique:=True
Sheet1.Range("O1").Value = "The List"
Sheet1.Range("O2").Delete Shift:=xlUp

' to assign keys
For i = 2 To LastMeter
Set CountOpt = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=r[0]c[-1]&r[0]c[-2]"
Sheet1.Cells(i, 11).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(c10:c10, r[0]c10)"

Next i

'to calculate averages
For x = 2 To LastMeter
If Sheet1.Cells(x, 11).Value = 1 Then
Sheet1.Cells(x, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=rc7"
ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(x, 11).Value > 1 Then
If Sheet1.Cells(x, 10).Value <> Sheet1.Cells(x - 1, 10).Value Then
Sheet1.Cells(x, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND((SUM(rc7:r[" & Sheet1.Cells(x, 11).Value - 1 & "]c7)/" & Sheet1.Cells(x, 11).Value & "),4)"
Else
Sheet1.Cells(x, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=r[-1]c12"
End If
End If

Next x

'to update final table
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim LastFinalList As Integer: LastFinalList = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row

For Col = 16 To 19

For c = 2 To LastFinalList

searchrange = Sheet1.Range("J:L")

lookfor = Sheet1.Cells(c, 15) & Sheet1.Cells(1, Col)
CountFor = Application.VLookup(lookfor, searchrange, 3, False)

If IsError(CountFor) Then
Sheet1.Cells(c, Col).Value = "0"
Else
Sheet1.Cells(c, Col).Value = CountFor

End If

Next c

Next Col

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheet1.Range("O1").Select

End Sub
```

Also, initially i had a SUMIF formula instead of `application.vlookup` to be input in each cell in the converted table. But the code was working as slow as now an was bit bulky, that's why i've decide to switch to VLOOKUP.

The thing is, if it actually the way application.vlookup works (with 0.3sec delay for each row), then i guess there's nothing that can be done, and i'm ok to accept that. Although, if that's not the case, i'd really appreciate if someone could help me out and speed up the process.

Thanks!

Comment: it looks like you are trying to replicate with a code something that is easily down with a pivot table?

Comment: Hi Raugmor. Might as well be true:) But there are two reasons for that. 1 - I'm not a big fan of pivot tables. 2 - I'm writing this macro for people who are not familiar with excel at all (i'm pretty sure i'f we'd change their computers for a typewriters, there will be now difference). That's why i've decided to make this converter, which will work in a button click.

Comment: You can redefine your LastFinalList variable something like

`LastFinalList = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count`

instead of explicitly defining used range.


Also use following line of code before your code
`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

(Turn screen updating off to speed up macro code.
User won't be able to see what the macro is doing, but it will run faster.)

After doing it; please let me know how faster your code runs than previous.

Comment: ok, as i don't see the full picture on the background, another thing might work is switching off calculations before you ran macro and then switching back on after, however it depends on how it affects the data whilst macro is running

Comment: Avidan, i've tried to switch off screen updating, but it didnt speed up the process. Re defining the LastFinalList - I'm a bit confused with the formula you suggested. Am i correct in assuming that instead of `UsedRange` i must enter my own range (for example "O1000")?

Comment: Just modify your data so you can produce a clean pivot table (e.g. extra columns to split 1a to 1 and a) it will be much quicker and easier to maintain. If your audience is for someone not familiar with Excel how do you expect them to maintain VBA?

Comment: Raugmor, same with switching off automatic calculations - no effect so far. as well. It didnt affect the `application.Vlookup` though. If you need any additional information re code/spreadsheet structure, i'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: If your range is fixed and just till "01000" then specify it explicitly. But if you may have only 10-12 Rows (also) then defining range explicitly as 01000 may waste few calculation cycles-as I feel

Comment: Hi mheptinstall. I dont expect them to maintain VBA at all :) Unforunately that will be my burden. Re modifying the table - again, then it comes to 1000+rows and 20+ columns, all in different formats and with double records, it takes ~1 hour to sort that pile of s**t the way we need it :(

Comment: Avidan, that's the case - the range is not fixed. It may be 100 rows today and 500+ rows tomorrow, depending on what type of data we receive. That's why i've used `Sheet1.Range("O1000").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Cooool.
Then please try with not defining the range explicitly; as I have suggested and please let me know if it works.
Buddy, here you are expecting at max 1000 Rows; so you have defined Range till 1000. If you were expecting at max 10000 Rows; then would you have used the same like Range("10000")?

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine your LastFinalList variable something like

```
LastFinalList = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

OR

```
LastFinalList = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```

instead of explicitly defining used range.

Also use following line of code before your code

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

(Turn screen updating off to speed up macro code. User won't be able to see what the macro is doing, but it will run faster.)

After the whole code runs you can(optional) turn screen updating on with

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: I've changed the LastFinalList variable as you suggested, to `Dim LastFinalList As Integer: LastFinalList = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row` and added the ScreenUpdate off/on. But again, without any results :( I've even tried to add `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`, but no improvements were noticed... I'll provide the full code in the main question, maybe it'll help to find the alaternatives. Thanks for spending your time on this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `application.vlookup` in my particular case was indeed working very slow (no idea why, though). I've managed to improve macro by replacing vlookup with SUMIF formula in each cell, so now the converted table is updated instantly. Thanks everyone who participated and provided their suggestions!